# Save and get Date format in symfony2 via ORM

Tags: php, symfony

According to this http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/date.html#format I created this form type:

```
->add('warranty', DateType::class, array(
          'widget' => 'single_text',
          'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd')
)
```

Here what i have in my entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(
 *     type="date"
 * )
 *
 * @JMS\Groups("list")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 */
protected $warranty;
```

And I'm trying to save date like this `2012-12-12`.

And this works fine, bun when I tried to get back data from DB i got this

```
2012-12-12T00:00:00+0200
```

I need work only with date, not datetime, can some one help me?

Comment: How/where do you display this? The php `\DateTime` has a `format` function: `$date->format('Y/m/d')` which returns a string of the date representation you want, but you cannot remove the time representation from the object itself. It shouldn't affect you anyway as the time is always 0 if not specified (which is true if the database value contains the date part only, not time..)

Comment: I saw it at /api/doc page, I will do something with it during View page generation. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine maps date sql fields to an instance of \DateTime class which always has time stored (set to zero).

You can consider using the date twig filter:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html

Or if you have localised pages, the localised date filter using the intl extension:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/intl.html